# nls missing value or infinity produced

Tags: r, dplyr, nls, tidymodels

I'm trying to model nested data with a Chapman-Richards function like this:
https://image.slideserve.com/575351/testing-eichhorn-s-rule35-n.jpg

My original data looks as follows:

```
structure(list(Site = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4), Height = c(2.4, 11.3, 20.5, 27.4, 32, 34.9, 2.45, 7.45, 13.05, 
17.7, 20.75, 22.8), Volume = c(12, 220, 605, 991, 1288, 1495, 
11, 106, 283, 473, 619, 723)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I create a growth model:

```
model <- function(data){
  nls(Volume~ a * (Height^b), data=data, start=c(Volume=200, Height=5,a=1,b=1))
}
```

When I nest my data to create a model for each nest:

```
Silver %>% group_by(Site_class) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(mod= map(.x=data, model))
```

I get the following error:

```
fitting parameters ‘a’, ‘b’ without any variables
Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
Called from: numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env)
```

I'm aware there may be very little variation in the data.

If I try alg="plinear", I get the following error:

```
fitting parameters ‘a’, ‘b’ without any variables
Error in qr.solve(QR.B, cc) : singular matrix 'a' in solve
Called from: qr.solve(QR.B, cc)
```

I have tried changing it to robustbase::nlrob in case that would perform better.

This changes the error code to:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: ~ 
   ^
Called from: parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE)
```

Does anyone know what's causing me this issue or how to solve it? Many thanks!

Comment: do the fits work if you do them one at a time, outside of the tidy/nested framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what `nls` is doing, it is estimating the values of parameters `a` and `b` in your case. Therefore there is no need to have start values for variables `Volume` and `Height`. These are simply the values in the dataset. If you remove them from the `start` argument, the error goes away and you get a model.

```
model <- function(data){
  nls(Volume~ a * (Height^b), data=data, start=c(a = 1, b = 1))
}
  
df %>% group_by(Site) %>% nest() %>% 
  mutate(mod= map(.x=data, model))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was almost sure there was a simple solution.